# Plotting a map : Rotating arrows for ocean surface currents

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

Here are the variables displayed by the netCDF file:
[image: 1]

I have written this code in order to draw Mediterranean surface currents with a netCDF file :

```
import netCDF4
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

nc=Dataset('datasets/essai.nc')

y = nc.variables['g0_lat_1']
y = np.array(y)

x = nc.variables['g0_lon_2']
x = np.array(x)

u = nc.variables['UOGRD_GDS0_DBSL']
u = np.array(u)
u = u[0, :, :]
u = np.deg2rad(u)

v = nc.variables['VOGRD_GDS0_DBSL']
v = np.array(v)
v = v[0, :, :]
v = np.deg2rad(v)

y, x = np.meshgrid(y,x)

plt.quiver(x [::10], y[::10], u[::10], v[::10], pivot='tail')
plt.show()
```

Which gives me this :
[image]

When I zoom in, we can see there are arrows and points : 
[image]
Firstly, I don't know what the points mean, I can't imagine coastlines. Then, all my arrows go to the same direction ! So I found on the forum this code :

```
# Calculate positions of vectors on map projection 
y, x = np.meshgrid(lat,lon)

# Calculate the orientation of the vectors
x1, y1 = m(lon+u, lat+v)
u_map, v_map = x1-x, y1-y

# Rescale the magnitudes of the vectors...
mag_scale = np.hypot(u_map, v_map) / np.hypot(u, v)
u_map /= mag_scale
v_map /= mag_scale

m.quiver(x, y, u_map, v_map)
plt.show()
```

But it returns me only an arrow. Have you got any idea?

Comment: do you have any documentation on what the data in the files _means_?  I suspect part of the problem is not properly interpreting your input data.

Comment: you also don't convert you lat-lons -> xy using a basemap projection, which I suspect you want to do.

Comment: @tcaswell lat and lon are the coordonates of the arrows (degrees), uogrd and vogrd are the componentof current (m/s) and yes I edit a Basemap with : m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=36.9000015258789,llcrnrlat=45.9000015258789,
   # urcrnrlon=-6,urcrnrlat=30,
   # projection='merc',resolution ='l')
which are the coordinates of the mediterranean zone (I edit my post to show you all the variables contained in the netcdf file)

Comment: Why are you converting the velocity field from degrees to radians?

Comment: @tcaswell someone told me to do that, is it wrong?

Comment: well, the data you have in the u and v components in m/s which are notable not degrees so dimensionally it makes no sense

Comment: @tcaswell Ok thanks for your explanations. So I removed it, but for the rotation, am I applying the right method?

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

You can try modify the code below to suit your data, also there are useful of examples on the [basemap](http://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plotting_data.html#quiver) website. However, if these plots are intended for publication you might be better off using [ncl](https://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Applications/index.shtml) which has plenty of tools for plotting meteorological/oceanographic data.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

x = np.linspace(-10, 40, 10)
y = np.linspace(25, 45, 10)
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(x, y)

u = np.random.random(np.shape(lons))
v = np.random.random(np.shape(lats))


m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-10.,llcrnrlat=25.,urcrnrlon=40.,urcrnrlat=45.,
            lon_0=10., lat_0=35,
            projection='lcc', resolution ='l')

m.drawcoastlines()

X,Y = m(lons,lats)
m.quiver(X,Y,u,v)

plt.show()
```